# compiler is showing ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException...i guess my logic is wrong somewhere

Tags: search, binary

```
static int binarySearch(int start, int end, int x, int[] arr) {

    while (start <= end) {
        int mid = (start + end) / 2;
        if (x > arr[mid]) {
            start = mid + 1;
        } else if (x < arr[mid]) {
            end = mid - 1;
        } else {
            return mid;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: `while(start<=end){` probably should be `while(start<end){`

Comment: You should tag the language you are using.